# Unity - Quaternions maximum value is always '1.0' and minimum value is always '-1.0'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, camera, quaternions

I am making a game where you play in the first-person perspective. I want to make it a little realistic by adding a head bobbing effect. This is already included in the Standard Asset pack 'Characters' that I am using, but I am also trying to adjust the rotation of the players head where it will tilt left and right when walking/running.

For some reason when I apply a quaternion to the local rotation of the camera the z value is between -1.0 and 1.0, but this is not what I want.

I have tried multiplying the z value by 360 but then still it gave me '1' as the maximum value.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Unless you know how `Quaternion`s work inside out, you shouldn't be meddling with the individual values because they do not directly store angle values anyway. You might want to look into `transform.eulerAngles` which allow you to use 3 angles XYZ like the one in the editor.

Comment: I also tried this, but how do I apply this on the local rotation since that requires a Quaternion and not a Vector3

Comment: Expected for max/min of quaternion component (-1, 1). It keeps magnitude of rotation radians/2.

It is not proper way of rotate object to individualy change the components of quaternion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Quaternion.Euler.

Example;

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 360));

Hope this helps.!

Comment: or `transform.rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 360)`